# Imagem em blob não aparece

Tags: imagem, laravel-5, bootstrap

Estou precisando fazer minhas imagens aparecer na `tag img` porém apenas algumas aparece, ja tirei todos os css e não é problema nisto.

Abaixo a foto que testifica que o html esta entendendo a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha página estou chamando as imagens assim:

```
@foreach($produto->imagens as $imagen)
    @if($imagen->FlgPrincipal == 0)
       <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="{{$imagen->BLOB}}" class="img-responsive img-normal">
       </div>
    @elseif($imagen->FlgPrincipal == 1)
       <div class="col-md-5">
          <img src="{{$imagen->BLOB}}" class="img-responsive img-principal">
       </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

O que poderia ser que está acontecendo ? Estou basicamente utilizando o `framework Laravel`

Comment: Se você clicar em cima da imagem com o botão direito e mandar exibir a imagem sozinha ele exibe?

Comment: sim, ela exibe perfeitamente

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Algo maluco é que quando atualizo a página umas outras some, e umas outras aparece, mais sem padrão definido

Comment: aparentemente o tamanho da imagem afeta, como resolver isto ?

Comment: Tem que padronizar o tamanho

Comment: Como posso fazer isto ? Utilizando laravel como framework ? Sabe como reduzir a qualidade da imagem caso o usuário envie algo com grande qualidade ?

Comment: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-image-upload-and-resize-example-using-intervention-image-packageexample.html da uma olhada nesse tutorial e também aqui já fiz um exemplo

Comment: @VirgilioNovic meu negocio é com blob, será que funciona ?

Comment: Na verdade não tem problema, é que as imagens são de tamanho diferente e precisam antes ter um padrão de tamanho, forma e qualidade. Funcionar.se fizer o processo antes de gravar no banco